# Spring IOC inmutable list

Tags: java, spring, list, inversion-of-control

i want something list this a inmutable List

```
final List<Student>students=Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
```

but i want it retrieve from Spring container how can i do it.

i have something like this

```
<util:list id="inmutableEmptyStudentList" value-type="com.model.Student">
```

but how can i tell Spring that creates my List using

```
Collections.EMPTY_LIST
```

any help is hugely appreciate.

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wouldn't be able to use `<util:list>`. You need to use a `static` factory method. Since `Collections` has an `emptyList()` method that returns the `EMPTY_LIST`, you can do

```
<bean id="immutableEmptyStudentList" class="java.util.Collections" factory-method="emptyList" />
```